# Jenkins Plugin - trend graphs don't show after upgrade to analysis-core v1.86

Tags: java, jenkins, xunit

I am struggling with the following problem:

In my Jenkins plugin, after updating dependency analysis-core from `1.49` to `1.86` trend graph doesn't show up in job page despite having a couple of successful runs.

Type of project: Freestyle Project 
I am using the latest Jenkins. I am able to debug my plugin in Eclipse IDE using `mvn hpi:run.`

I would be very thankful for any advice how to resolve this problem or even small hints.

Other dependencies I have:

```
-xunit 
-dashboard-view 
-matrix-project
```